# hr tag causing margin between two sections

Tags: html, css, web

I'm building a personal website and have sections that I want to split with hr tags. However, I keep getting this weird spacing when I use the tag.

[image]

(the yellow is one section, and the purple is another, the green is the color of the background of the page)

I'm trying to fix it by changing margins, paddings, etc, but nothing seems to work, any ideas?

```
hr {
padding: 0px;
height: 1px;
border: none;
}
```

Comment: please show us css and html markup, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to get that by setting the margin to 0:

```
hr {
  margin: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5m5wad4r/

If that's not working, maybe the sections themselves have margins, and it's not the `hr`?